# re-using QT CSS in desktop C++ application and wordpress at the same

Tags: css, qt

I know this might sound weird, but I'm trying to build a scalable and consistent front-end "component library" (most specifically CSS and design styles) for a product and its "marketing wordpress website". We have a complicated C++ desktop application that is similar to a 3D software. I used material design principles for icons, colors, styles, but I want to build a consistent design "system" that can work both on the web and our GUI, I want to avoid having multiple people creating different versions of the same thing (like wasting time creating multiple button styles)

I understand QSS is not CSS, but the syntax is very similar, is there a way to re-use the CSS sheets from QT in wordpress? I want to avoid having to copy and paste from QT to wordpress as wel -  it's ok if the wordpress classes are not in QT, but it would be good if I change something in QT (like a button color) that would be reflected in our wordpress stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QSS supports only resticted subset of CSS 2 + some features from CSS 3 + some custom qt-features. Your idea sounds good, but in practice you will have a lot of problems, because QSS is not enough for gui customization in Qt. You also need to configure layouts, do some magic with size policies of widgets.

You may create you own template engine that will convert some input to QSS and CSS. But you will spend much more time/money for development of such feature.

If you want, you may use QtQuick / QML for GUI and create your own template engine that will convert CSS to QtQuick styles.